# How to separate the attribute from xpath?

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to split attribute from xPath .

```
$xPath = "/configuration/system.serviceModel/services/service/endpoint/@binding"

$node = $xPath.split("@")[0]
$attribute = $xPath.split("@")[1]
```

$attribute is having the correct value "binding"

but the node xpath is "/configuration/system.serviceModel/services/service/endpoint/". there is an extra "/" at then end . I want to get rid of that.

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-split` operator:

```psh
$xPath = "/configuration/system.serviceModel/services/service/endpoint/@binding"

$node, $attribute = $xPath -split '/@', 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .Replace() method to just replace /binding/ with /binding, like so:

```
$xPath.Replace("/endpoint/","/endpoint")
>/configuration/system.serviceModel/services/service/endpoint
```